# Error creating bean with name 'deliveryPartnerRecordController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dService'; nested exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can anyone help me figure out my mistake?

**JPA function:**

```
@Query("select d from deliverypartnerrecord d where d.status = :d_status and d.id = :d_id")
public Deliverypartnerrecord findDeliveryPartnerRecordById(@Param("d_id") int id, @Param("d_status") String status);
```

**error:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'deliveryPartnerRecordController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryPartnerRecordService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryPartnerRecordRepo' defined in com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.repository.DeliveryPartnerRecordRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.model.Deliverypartnerrecord com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.repository.DeliveryPartnerRecordRepo.findDeliveryPartnerRecordById(int,java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.model.Deliverypartnerrecord com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.repository.DeliveryPartnerRecordRepo.findDeliveryPartnerRecordById(int,java.lang.String)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.model.Deliverypartnerrecord com.diatozSnacks.snacks_management.repository.DeliveryPartnerRecordRepo.findDeliveryPartnerRecordById(int,java.lang.String)!
```

Comment: As the error tells you the JPQL is wrong. Your entity, I assume is named `Deliverypartnerrecord` **not** `deliverypartnerrecord`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query syntax to the following:

```
@Query(value="select * from deliverypartnerrecord d where d.status = :d_status and d.id = :d_id", nativeQuery=true)
```

And now it's working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).